# How to populate a table with data vertically?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, haml

I have three arrays I'd like to arrange vertically in an HTML table. Each array will have its data populated in a column from top to bottom.

For example, I have three arrays:

```
fruit = ['pear', 'apple', 'orange']
veges = ['corn', 'radish', 'lettuce']
meat = ['beef', 'chicken', 'pork']
```

I want the table to look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      pear
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      corn
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      beef
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      apple
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      radish
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      chicken
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      orange
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      lettuce
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      pork
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Same problem, no solution (yet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669957/transpose-a-html-table

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128663/display-data-in-columns-not-rows-using-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use [`Array#transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-transpose) to rearrange things to match what your `<table>` should look like:

```
rows = [ fruit, veges, meat ].transpose
```

Now `rows` will look like:

```
[
  ["pear", "corn", "beef"],
  ["apple", "radish", "chicken"],
  ["orange", "lettuce", "pork"]
]
```

and generating your table is a simple matter of iterating over `rows`:

```
%table
  - rows.each do |row|
    %tr
      - row.each do |food|
        %td= food
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this website: [Generate vertically-ordered HTML table in Ruby](https://web.archive.org/web/20120804075127/http://mattly.me/snippet/2011/11/23/generate-vertically-ordered-html-table-in-ruby)

Here is the relevant code (the instance variables in this example are used simply for clarity in identifying what controls the number of columns and rows):

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% 0.upto(@rows_per_column-1).each do |row| %>
      <tr>
        <% 0.upto(@columns-1).each do |column| %>
        <% index = row + (column * @rows_per_column) %>
        <td><%= index %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```